# where to download multi language word list from Wiktionary?

Tags: nlp, n-gram, wiktionary

I was wondering if there was a place to download multi-language word lists from Wiktionary?

Answer (score 2):

Lists of the words contained in the various Wiktionary versions can all be constructed by parsing the XML/database dump files found at [dumps.wikimedia.org](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/).